# Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Why do I get "Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration" when I try to execute the main? I'm using Hibernate 4.2.11.Final with a PostGreSQL DB. This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ProgettoPersonaleDB</property>
        <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <!-- <mapping class="org.javabrains.sanjaya.dto.UserDetails" /> -->
        <mapping resource="Players.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="Users.hbm.xml" />
        <!-- <mapping class="ProgettoPersonale.src.main.java.ProgettoPersonale.ProgettoPersonale.Users.java"/> -->
        <mapping
            class="ProgettoPersonale/src/main/java/ProgettoPersonale/ProgettoPersonale/Users.java" />
        /
        <mapping
            class="ProgettoPersonale/src/main/java/ProgettoPersonale/ProgettoPersonale/Players" />


        <class-cache class="org.hibernate.auction.Item" usage="read-write"/>
        <class-cache class="org.hibernate.auction.Bid" usage="read-only"/>
        <collection-cache collection="org.hibernate.auction.Item.bids" usage="read-write"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And this is the full stack-trace, thank you!

```
    02:02:35.149 [main] DEBUG o.h.i.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver - Located [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd] in classpath
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ProgettoPersonale.ProgettoPersonale.ManagePlayers.addPlayer(ManagePlayers.java:27)
    at ProgettoPersonale.ProgettoPersonale.PlayersMain.main(PlayersMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2098)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2015)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1994)
    at ProgettoPersonale.ProgettoPersonale.ManagePlayers.addPlayer(ManagePlayers.java:21)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 36; columnNumber: 20; Il contenuto del tipo di elemento "session-factory" deve corrispondere a "(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1994)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:879)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2095)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a extra / in the middle of the conf:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ProgettoPersonaleDB</property>
    <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!-- <mapping class="org.javabrains.sanjaya.dto.UserDetails" /> -->
    <mapping resource="Players.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Users.hbm.xml" />
    <!-- <mapping class="ProgettoPersonale.src.main.java.ProgettoPersonale.ProgettoPersonale.Users.java"/> -->
    <mapping
        class="ProgettoPersonale/src/main/java/ProgettoPersonale/ProgettoPersonale/Users.java" />
    <mapping
        class="ProgettoPersonale/src/main/java/ProgettoPersonale/ProgettoPersonale/Players" />


    <class-cache class="org.hibernate.auction.Item" usage="read-write"/>
    <class-cache class="org.hibernate.auction.Bid" usage="read-only"/>
    <collection-cache collection="org.hibernate.auction.Item.bids" usage="read-write"/>

</session-factory>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an extra '/' on line 26 of the hibernate.cfg.xml. Remove that and try again.